# A different kind of weighing problem

Tags: mathematics, weighing

A puzzle I enjoyed, from the November 1983 issue of the
American Mathematical Monthly:

Problem E3023: Proposed by J. G. Mauldon (a well-known retrograde analysis chess problem composer too!)

You are given an accurate indicating spring scale (not a balance)
and seven coins, each of which weighs either x or y, where x and y are
unknown.  In five weighings, determine the weight of each coin.

I've had a peek at the two published solutions now. The first, case-based one is to me not very inspiring, but even the second solution by Mauldon himself (who unfortunately passed some years ago) is in my humble opinion not as cool and generalizable as the solution I will try to lead towards here.

Let's say to simplify things that we must specify the full set of 5 weighings right at the beginning. Letting the 7 weights be $a,b,c,d,e,f,g$, an example attempt of 5 weighings could be:

> $c+d$
>   $d+e$
>   $a+b+c$
>   $e+f+g$
>   $b+f$

However this doesn't work because, supposing that the two coins weigh $1$ & $2$ then the following 2 assignments for the individual coin weights:

> $1,2,1,2,2,1,1$
>   $1,1,2,1,1,2,1$

will both generate the results for the 5 weighings to be:

> $3,3,4,4,3$

Often it's good idea to attack a problem by going for a simpler case first. Up to symmetry, there are exactly two solutions to identify 5 coins in 4 weighings. Here's one:

> b+c+d+e
>  a+b+d
>  a+b+e
>  a+c

Comment: Maybe it's worth mentioning that the solution involves a very large tree of possibilities and a lot of patience. I didn't have so much patience and looked into the [solutions](https://www.jstor.org/stable/2325219) published more than 5 years later.

Comment: @A. P. Well, looking up the answers is one way to solve a published problem. The solution we ourselves found didn't involve any "tree of possibilties", and was much more compact. Thanks for the link to the published solutions, but I won't look at them yet. There's also the question of different numbers of coins and weighings.

Comment: Starting from smaller numbers of coins already shows how interesting this puzzle is. Even 4 coins seem to require a full 4 weighings.

Comment: Do you happen to know an example solution for five coins that would take only 4 weighings, and has it been verified?

Comment: @micsthepick: There are exactly two solutions with 5 coins in 4 weighings. I will put one in the base note.

Comment: If it helps to know, @Laska, some of us haven't given up trying to crack this tasty nut of a puzzle and still have leads to follow before looking for more hints. Just your saying that in-print solutions are more complex than necessary is a big hint even without knowing anything more about those solutions.

Comment: Is it necessary to state all the weighings up front, or was that just part of an example?

Comment: @Lawrence: it's not necessary, but very desirable. One of the two published solutions (linked to above) was a laborious case-based approach, which I am trying to avoid because it's quite boring. The second solution, by Mauldon, just pulls one static list of weighings out of a hat, and then to my mind spends too much time justifying it. These days, we ought to be able to determine all up-front solutions to the 7-5 problems, as we can for the 5-4 problem, and can hopefully go on to solve 9-6 and further.

Comment: Thanks. To give me some idea of the kind of solution you're looking for, can you please say how you would prove the 5-4 solution in a non case-based and non-analytic manner?

Comment: @Lawrence. There are two parts to the solution. The more interesting and harder part is the first one, which is to discover the good sets of weighings. The second part, to verify that a proposed set of weighings works, is simpler and basically means that the function from coin weights to weighing results must be 1-1. This second part gives a necessary and sufficient solution for a set of weighings to work. Hope this helps: if you want more just ask.

Comment: Thanks for explaining your priorities for this puzzle. I'm working on a slightly different approach to those currently presented below and will try to factor your comments into my solution (assuming it works :) - I encountered a problematic edge case).

Answer (score 4):

I wrote a computer program simply trying to:

1- Create all possible matrices which represents our $a$, $b$, $c$ values in a summation by $1$ or $0$ if they exist in the sum, such as below:

> $\begin{bmatrix}
> 0 &0  &0  &1  &1  &0  &1 \\ 
> 0 &0  &0  &0  &0  &0  &1 \\ 
> 1 &0  &0  &1  &0  &0  &1 \\ 
> 0 &0  &0  &0  &0  &1  &1 \\ 
> 0 &1  &1  &0  &1  &1  &0 \\ 
> 1 &0  &0  &1  &1  &0  &0 \\
> 1 &0  &0  &1  &1  &0  &0 
> \end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}
> a\\ 
> b\\ 
> c\\ 
> d\\ 
> e\\ 
> f\\ 
> g
> \end{bmatrix}= \begin{bmatrix}
> S_1\\ 
> S_2\\ 
> S_3\\ 
> S_4\\ 
> S_5\\ 
> S_6\\ 
> S_7
> \end{bmatrix}$

So I represent everything as a matrix. In my program, It tries to create all possible combinations by using $1$ and $0$ and the program makes sure that every column has at least one $1$ and none of the rows are the same.

2- Secondly, I choose two values for our values ($a$,$b$,$c$,... etc.) and find our $S$ values for each possible two values. so there are $2^7$ possible values you can choose for your chosen matrix above. and every values I find $S$ sums. Let's say I choose $2$,$2$,$4$,$2$... etc

3- By using these $S$ values and the original matrix, I choose another two values which are different than our $a$, $b$, $c$,... (let say $3$,$1$,$1$,$3$...), and find other $S_t$ values.

4- Lastly, In part 3 if I encounter $S_t$ values which are the same $S$ values for each sum in part 2, I conclude that that matrix is not the matrix I need to use to find $a$,$b$,$c$, ... values since there could be other possible values satisfies the same conditions/equations.

If you are looking for 7 value and 5 equations, one of the possible answer becomes:

> $\begin{bmatrix}
> 1 &1  &0  &1  &0  &0  &0\\ 
> 1 &1  &1  &0  &0  &0  &1\\ 
> 0 &1  &1  &1  &0  &1  &0\\ 
> 1 &0  &0  &1  &1  &1  &1\\ 
> 1 &1  &1  &0  &1  &1  &0\\ 
> \end{bmatrix}$

Here is [the code](http://rextester.com/GZZ47625), you can change ks and d values to find for different results, such as if you input ks as 5, and d as 4. You will get instant answers, but it takes about an hour to find a 7 and 5. The program can be optimized better, but it works without any problem at the moment.

Here is another solution:

> $\begin{bmatrix}
> 1 &1  &1  &1  &1  &1  &0\\ 
> 1 &1  &1  &1  &0  &0  &1\\ 
> 0 &0  &0  &1  &0  &1  &1\\ 
> 0 &0  &1  &0  &1  &0  &1\\ 
> 0 &1  &0  &1  &1  &0  &0\\ 
> \end{bmatrix}$

### Previous Solution

First weigh the first three:

> $ w_1=a+b+c$

Then the other three:

> $ w_2=d+e+f$

Then the some mix:

> $w_3=a+e+f$

then the last mix:

> $w_4=b+d+e$

we also have differences as an extra information among these $w$s. but what can we do with these differences, what kind of information can be gained?

Let's do the math:

> There are a few possibilities for the $w$s: $3x$, $2x+y$, $x+2y$ and $3y$ and the differences could be $0$, $x-y$, $2x-2y$ and $3x-3y$. If you notice, the differences have some relation, the ratio between them is *constant*. So by using those $w$'s, we have the lots of relation we can find among $a,b,c,d,e,f$ except $g$ since we did not weigh it at all. Lastly we weigh our $g$ and find one of the weights! Then the rest becomes easily and quickly, for example let say:
>
> $ w_1=7$

Then the other three:

> $ w_2=15$

Then the some mix:

> $w_3=11$

then the last mix:

> $w_4=11$

and last weight:

> $g=5$

from the difference between $w_2$ and $w_3$, it can be concluded that $a=1$ and $d=5$ since $g=5$. Moreover, from $g=5$, so you can easily say that $e=5$ and $f=5$. The only problem becomes $b$ and $c$. But since we have seperate results, $w_1$ and $w_4$, $b$ becomes $1$ and as a result $c=5$.

This is applicable to most kind of combinations.

Comment: Certainly will give you +1 for a brave effort. But I don't think the combinations you have chosen work out. If a...g are respectively 3,3,1,3,1,3,3 or 2,2,3,2,3,2,3 then you will still get the same results for your weighings: 7,7,7,7,3. (For verification, I am taking your weighings to be a+b+c, d+e+f, a+e+f, b+d+e, g). For those who were a bit baffled about the problem, this non-solution is probably a very good indication what we are trying to achieve.

Comment: @Laska you are right, i need to edit the methodology after getting 2 or 3 equal ws, i believe it is possible to overcome this situation.

Comment: Thanks for your continuing interest in this problem. I am not sure I follow your new methodology (e.g. why a 7x7 matrix is relevant). But I guess the "proof would be in the pudding", as they say. If my arithmetic is right, then your 7x5 possible solution gives exactly the same 5 weighing results for 2,1,1,1,2,1,1 as for 1,1,2,2,1,1,2, namely: 4,4,5,5,7.

Comment: @Laska seems my program has a little bug :) i will update the answer...

Comment: @Laska I believe that I have fixed the bug in my program, could you recheck again? If there is no bug left, I will share my code.

Comment: Hi I think your latest solution works :D

Comment: Thanks for posting the code. I'm quite busy today, but a couple of comments. 1) When I run with ks=5 & d=4, the first answer (11110,11001,10101,10011) has duplicate solutions 22223 & 51111 which both yield weighings 8777. 2) You restrict each row to have no greater number of 1s than the previous row, to remove some duplicates. But we catch many more duplicates if you say each row is e.g. a bitstring, and must be lower than the one before. This is only one optimization, but worth it cos it helps us check solutions, and saves a lot of time.

Comment: So if i < j are rows then the row bitstrings r_i > r_j if considered as binary numbers. Moreover, we can also say that *not* r_i >> r_j, where ">>" is bitwise comparison. In the new answer you gave for 7 by 5 (1111110,1111001,0001011,0010101,0101100), the 1st row is a superset of the last row (1111110 >> 0101100) and could be replaced by 1010010. This reduces hugely the number of possibilities to be searched. In any case, the answer has duplicate solutions 3322223 & 1155111 both giving weights 14,13,7,7,7. Can't wait for the next version of your program! :D

Comment: Also your program doesn't give right values for trivial cases e.g. ks=d=3, ks=d=4. Please don't take my responses as at all negative - I think your program's great, and I just want to help it converge to magnificence as soon as possible :D Handling trivial cases is an easy debugging step.

Comment: @ i found where the problem was, gonna post the new answer soon! thanks for your comments :)

Answer (score 2):

weigh all 7. ax+by=c ; a+b=7
weigh 5. ax+by+d=c ; a+b=5
Determine the total wight of the two coins off the scale (i.e. d).
weigh 3 ax+by+d+e=c ; a+b=3
Determine the total weight of the new two coins off the scale (i.e. e)
weigh 1 coin. ax+d+e+f=c ; a=1
Determine the total weight of the new two coins off the scale (i.e. f)
detemine x as the value of this last coin.

Subtract x from each d, e, f.

if d=2x or e=2x or f=2x, we know for certain both coins weigh x.

where d!=2x or e!=2x or f!=2x, we know for certain at least one corresponsing coin weighs y.

given d!=2x,
if e!=d and e!=2x,
d=2y or d=y+x and
e=2y iff d!=2y.

Therefore for the fifth and final weighing, weigh 1 coin from d along with the final coin, which is x.
We can now deterimine all the weights of the coins by knowing if d=2y, or d=y+x

Comment: If I’ve understood you properly, then I don’t think your solution can work. For example there is no weighing in which only one of the two coins that make up e appears. So if one is x and one is y, we can’t tell which is which. By the way in my own thinking, I have always been assuming that one weighing is never a strict subset of another so e.g. I would never weigh 7 and then 5 but instead 2 and then 5. It’s equivalent but simpler.

Comment: >For example there is no weighing in which only one of the two coins that make up e appears.
//

I see what you mean!

Answer (score 2):

<sup>(This initial write-up is half rushed, late in the day.
 More write-up is half ready.)</sup>

**A nearly complete solution,
  with an incomplete** (for now) **explanation**

This refreshingly juicy puzzle
would be a lot easier with unlimited copies of each coin
but, alas, only one of each is available.
 
What to do?
 
Simulate multiple copies (in stage 3)!
 
Here’s how.

 
Stage 1. Weigh 5 specific combinations of the 7 coins.

 
Stage 2. Determine the mystery weights, *x* and *y*.

 
Stage 3. Determine which coins weigh *x* and which weigh *y*.

Assume that *x* < *y*
and that each of these weights is represented by at least one coin.
(A future edit is planned to justify this assumption.)

**Stage 1. Weigh 5 specific combinations of the 7 coins.**

> ```
>              P  =                       f + g
>              Q  =           c   +   e   +   g
>              R  =       b   +   d + e   +   g
>              S  =   a     +     d + e   +   g
>              T  =   a + b + c + d + e + f    
>
>
>  Example:    x  =  1.1  =  a, b, c, d, f
>              y  =  3.3  =  e, g
>
>              P  =                                 1.1 + 3.3   =    4.4
>              Q  =               1.1    +    3.3    +    3.3   =    7.7
>              R  =         1.1    +    1.1 + 3.3    +    3.3   =    8.8
>              S  =   1.1       +       1.1 + 3.3    +    3.3   =    8.8
>              T  =   1.1 + 1.1 + 1.1 + 1.1 + 3.3 + 1.1         =    8.8
> ```

**Stage 2. Determine the mystery weights, *x* and *y*.**

This stage is admittedly sketchy, but go ahead and
scale the weighings’ results as specified,
then stretch and translate those scaled weighings
to fit on the displayed grid.
 
The grid will indicate what coefficients to use
in a set of linear equations that solve for *x* and *y*.

> ```
>      Scaled weighings to align         Fit them onto the vertical bars in this grid
>
>                                      0      1/6 1/4 1/3     1/2     2/3 3/4 5/6      1
>                                      .       .   .   .       .       .   .   .       .
>                6P                   2|0      .   .          1|1          .   .      0|2
>                4Q                   3|0      .      2|1      .      1|2      .      0|3
>                3R                   4|0         3|1  .      2|2      .  1|3         0|4
>                3S                   4|0         3|1  .      2|2      .  1|3         0|4
>                2T                   6|0     5|1  .  4|2     3|3     2|4  .  1|4     0|6
>                                      .       .   .   .       .       .   .   .       .
>                                      .       .   .   .       .       .   .   .       .
>   Example:                           .       .   .   .       .       .   .   .       .
>                                      .       .   .                       .   .       .
>      6P  =  6(4.4)  =  26.4          |       .             26.4              .       |
>      4Q  =  4(7.7)  =  30.8          |               |       .     30.8              |
>      3R  =  3(8.8)  =  26.4          |           |   .     26.4      .   |           |
>      3S  =  3(8.8)  =  26.4          |           |   .     26.4      .   |           |
>      2T  =  2(8.8)  =  17.6          |     17.6  .   |       |       |   .   |       |
>
>
>      Equations     /   P  =  4.4  =  1x + 1y    (because  6P = 26.4  aligns with "1|1")
>      indicated    /    Q  =  7.7  =  1x + 2y    (   "     4Q = 30.8       "      "1|2")
>      by numbers  <     R  =  8.8  =  2x + 2y    (   "     3R = 26.4       "      "2|2")
>      at vertical  \    S  =  8.8  =  2x + 2y    (   "     3S = 26.4       "      "2|2")
>      bars above    \   T  =  8.8  =  5x + 1y    (   "     2T = 17.6       "      "5|1")
>
>      This solves to    x = 1.1  and  y = 3.3
> ```

**Stage 3. Determine which coins weigh *x* and which weigh *y*.**

This determined how to select coins for the weighings
and was especially fun to work out.
 
Calculate *N* by combining all five weighings.

```
           N  =  (62P + 15Q + 13R + 12S - 11T - 203x) / (y-x)


Example:   N  =  (62(4.4) + 15(7.7) + 13(8.8) + 12(8.8) - 11(8.8) - 203(1.1)) / 2.2
              =  131
```

Now decompose *N* into...

```
           N  =   1A  +  2B  +  4C  +  14D  +  29E  +  51F  +  102G

           ...where A, B, C, D, E, F and G are each either 0 or 1.

           This interprets N as a mixed-base binary-digit number, each
           digit of which tells whether its corresponding coin weighs x or y.


Example:  131 =  1(0) + 2(0) + 4(0) + 14(0) + 29(1) + 51(0) + 102(1)

   Thus     A = B = C = D = F = 0         and   E = G = 1

     so     a = b = c = d = f = x = 1.1   and   e = g = y = 2.2
```

It’ll be fun to explain this better in a future edit but, for now,
the approach can be summarized by saying that
it simulates a single weighing that includes multiple copies of each coin.

> ```
>                       f g  -.
>                       f g   |
>                       f g   |
>                       f g   |  J = 62 copies of weighing P
>                       f g   |
>                       f g   |
>                       f g   |
>                        :   -'
>                 c . e . g  -.
>                 c . e . g   |
>                 c . e . g   |  K = 15 copies of Q
>                 c . e . g   |
>                 c . e . g   |
>                      :     -'
>               b . d e . g  -.
>               b . d e . g   |
>               b . d e . g   |  L = 13 copies of R
>               b . d e . g   |
>                     :      -'
>             a . . d e . g  -.
>             a . . d e . g   |  M = 12 copies of S
>             a . . d e . g   |
>                    :       -'
>          -  a b c d e f .  -.
>          -  a b c d e f .   |  N = 11 copies of T, which are subtracted
>          -  a b c d e f .   |
>                   :        -'
>        --------------------------
>         (M-N)a + (L-N)b + (K-N)c + (L+M-N)d + (K+L+M-N)e + (J-N)f + (J+K+L+M)g
>
>     This simulates a weighing with the following numbers of coins:
>
>     1 x a,  2 x b,  4 x c,  14 x d,  29 x e,  51 x f,  102 x g
> ```

The goal was to have more copies of each successive coin
than the combined number of all (alphabetically) previous coins.
 
Material is being written up to demonstrate how
the 5-coins-and-4-weighings version of this puzzle was solved
and how that led to this solution.

Comment: Typo up there: After decomposing _N_, `  =   =   = 2.2` should be `  =   =   = 3.3`

Comment: thanks for your continuing energy. The solution you propose for 7 weighings and 5 coins is incorrect. For example 3,3,3,3,1,1,3 & 2,2,2,3,3,2,2 both yield weighings 4,7,10,10,14. Please publish your 5 by 4 solution.

Comment: Wow, @Laska, good counter-example,
it reveals how important the identification of _X_ and _y_ are.
I keep finding more and more interesting ways
to identify which coin is which after knowing _x_ and _y_, though,
and am still having too much fun to ask for hints.
Thank you for such an intriguing twist on coin-weighing puzzles.

Answer (score 1):

I've been playing with this all day, and I'm afraid I do not have the math to back this answer up.  I've done enough guess-and-check, but feel free to explain to me how this works (if it does):

I chose to start from the "center".  The first task is to figure out what the difference between x and y is, and from there, weigh the coins such that they are intertwined:

Given coins $a, b, c, d, e, f,$ and $g$

1. $c + d$
2. $d + e$

If 1 and 2 weigh differently, then this is the difference in weight between $c$ and $e$.  There is still an issue with various factorizations, but knowing the sum really cuts things down.

3. $a + b + c$
4. $e + f + g$

If 1 and 2 did not produce $x$ and $y$, then these will (I think).

Finally, step 5 figures out the correct placement of $x$ and $y$ within $a, b, f,$ and $g$

5. $b + f$

[image]

I think this pattern hold with more coins. For example, if $g$ is known, and we add $h$ and $i$, then one weighing is $g + h + i$, and the other is $a + h$ to get the correct order.  As more letters are added, the original pivot point would need to be moved to the center (adding $j$ and $k$ would require the first two weighings to include $d, e,$ and $f$.

Comment: +1 for a solid attempt, but I know already it's not going to work out. It will take more space than I have here, so I will put it in the base post.

Comment: If {a=d=g=x, b=c=e=f=y} then your weighings give the results (x+y,x+y,x+2y,x+2y,2y). However you get the same results with {a=b=d=g=f=y, c=e=x}, so it does not distinguish between these two cases.